# Curves in polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why there are different units used for rectangular and polar coordinates?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw node [red] at (-1,.25) {\scriptsize{Kardioida $r=5-5\sin \theta$}};
\draw[color=red,domain=0:6.28,samples=200,smooth] plot (canvas polar cs:angle=\x r,radius=      {5-5*sin(\x r)});    %r = angle en radian
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use `canvas polar cs`, the radius is taken to be in TeX points and `5pt` is not very big.  To get the plot in the "natural" coordinates, use the `xy polar` syntax or use the implicit form, `(<angle>:<radius>)`.  What is perhaps a bit confusing about the implicit form is that it is a shorthand for *both* `canvas polar cs` and for `xy polar cs`.  The rule is that if you supply an explicit length, it is `canvas`, but if you don't then it is `xy`.

Thus the lower two examples produce something that is on the right scale (I shrank the size to get it to fit on the page):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65446/86}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw node [red] at (-1,.25) {\scriptsize{Kardioida $r=5-5\sin
\theta$}};
\draw[color=red,domain=0:6.28,samples=200,smooth] plot (canvas polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius=      {5-5*sin(\x r)});    %r = angle en radian
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw node [red] at (-1,.25) {\scriptsize{Kardioida $r=5-5\sin
\theta$}};
\draw[color=red,domain=0:6.28,samples=200,smooth] plot (canvas polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius=      {.5cm-.5cm*sin(\x r)});    %r = angle en
radian
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw node [red] at (-1,.25) {\scriptsize{Kardioida $r=5-5\sin
\theta$}};
\draw[color=red,domain=0:6.28,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius=      {.5-.5*sin(\x r)});    %r = angle en radian
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

In PSTricks, we can use `\psset{runit=1.2cm,unit=\psrunit}` to change the radial unit and rectangular unit. In this example, I made all equal.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset{runit=1.2cm,unit=\psrunit}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[axesstyle=polar,subticklinestyle=dashed,subticks=2,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](3,3)
\psplot[polarplot,algebraic=true,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,plotpoints=2000]{0}{TwoPi}{1.5-1.5*sin(3*x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

An animation might help us to choose a good constant for the function.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{runit=1cm,unit=\psrunit}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[axesstyle=polar,subticklinestyle=dashed,subticks=2,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](3,3)
\psplot[polarplot,algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,plotpoints=2000]{0}{TwoPi}{1.5-1.5*sin(\i*x)}
\rput(0,-3.5){\scriptsize Kardioida \ifnum\i=1\relax$r=1.5-1.5\sin \theta$\else$r=1.5-1.5\sin(\i \theta)$\fi}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```