# How to plot a curve in a polar form r = f(Θ)?

Tags: diagrams, plot, graphs

Can we use LaTeX to make the graph of `$\rho = \sec(\theta)$`?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65447/15925 .

Comment: You have a list of your questions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36688/benedito). Some of them have already had answers. If the answers satisfied you, please kindly accept them by clicking the check mark button below the score labels. Optionally you should vote them up by clicking the upward arrow button. You can also vote them down but only for the extreme  cases!

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) to achieve this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}
            \def\FREQUENCY{3}
            \addplot[red,domain=0:360,samples=360,smooth] (x,{30-8*sin(\FREQUENCY*x)});
            \addplot[dashed,domain=0:2*pi] (deg(x),30);
            \addplot[mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(0,0)};
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The source code is self-explanatory for anyone who have minimal experience in LaTeX.

**Note:** `pgfplots` by default uses degrees, for using radians you then need to convert it to degree via `deg()` function.

[image: polar plot]

And the `\rho=\sec\theta` (that's a pretty ugly function to plot it on the polar axis):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}
            \addplot[red,domain=-42:42,samples=360,smooth] (x,{sec(x)});
            \addplot[mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(0,0)};
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sec(theta)]

Comment: It is not `\rho=\sec \theta`.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot: I've added the `\rho=\sec\theta`. It's a straight line indeed.

Answer (score 6):

The polar with the corresponding cartesian plot:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[axesstyle=polar,subticklinestyle=dashed,subticks=2,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](3,0)
 \psplot[polarplot,algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,plotpoints=500,
      yMaxValue=3.5]{Pi neg}{Pi}{1/(cos(x))}
 \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue,plotpoints=5000,yMaxValue=3.5]{Pi neg}{Pi}{1/(cos(x))}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to see the calculated points use `showpoints`:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,subticklinestyle=dashed,subticks=2,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](3,0)
    \psplot[polarplot,algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt,plotpoints=25,showpoints,
      yMaxValue=3.5]{Pi neg}{Pi}{1/(cos(x))}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A recommended solution with PSTricks. `\rho=\sec\theta` represents the line `x=1`. So the correct curve should be like below.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset{runit=1.2cm,unit=\psrunit}
\pstVerb{/const 2 def}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,subticklinestyle=dashed,subticks=2,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](3,3)
    \psplot[polarplot,algebraic=true,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,plotpoints=1000,yMaxValue=3.5,yMinValue=-3.5]{0}{TwoPi}{const/(cos(x))}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My package [`xpicture`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xpicture) plots polar curves (or more general, parametric curves).

For example

```
% Cardioide: r = 1+cos t
\SUMfunction{\ONEfunction}{\COSfunction}{\ffunction} % Define f(t)=1 + cos t
\POLARfunction{\ffunction}{\cardioide}  % Declare \cardioide as r=f(\phi)
% \degreespolarlabels              % Uncomment to label angles in degrees

\begin{center}
  \def\runitdivisions{2}              % 2 divisions of unity in the r-axis
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1.5cm}
  \begin{Picture}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
    \polargrid{2}{16}  % Draw a polar grid for 0<r<2 and 16 divisions of circle
    \pictcolor{blue}\linethickness{1pt}
    \PlotParametricFunction[20]{\cardioide}{0}{\numberTWOPI} 
                                         % Draw \cardioide for 0<\phi<2\pi
  \end{Picture}

  $\rho=1+\cos\phi$
\end{center}
```

[image: The cardioide curve]